# Setting Up Arduino Uno IDE on Ubuntu

Tags: serial-port, arduino

I am new to Ubuntu (And I love it). I want to burn a code to my Arduino Uno. When uploading the code, there's an error message saying, `Serial Port COM1 not fount found. Did you select the correct one from tools -> serial port menu?`. Now, visiting the tools, I can't select serial port because it is disabled. I am attaching a screen-shot of how it looks. I have done something similar in windows. How to find the serial port on Ubuntu?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

COM1 is a Windows(TM) designation - it will look like /dev/ttyACM0, /dev/ttyUSB0 or similar in Linux.

Greyed out port tends to mean you haven't set the board type first - go through the settings in `arduino` Tools menu & set board to 'Uno', you should see the 'port' enable & auto-fill as well, most likely.

Answer (score 12):

In my case this error was because in the newer versions of Ubuntu the built in braile reader (brltty) was grabbing the port.  I could see this when I used the command

```
sudo dmesg | tail -f
```

this showed the tty being disconnected from the port

[  771.927380] usb 2-1.1: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by ch341 while 'brltty' sets config #1

[  771.928207] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: ch341-uart converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0

explained very well here:

[/dev/ttyUSB0 not present in Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403705/dev-ttyusb0-not-present-in-ubuntu-22-04)

the actual fix I applied was

```
sudo apt remove brltty   (nb plug and replug the arduino afterwards)
```

...as suggested by Jarosław Jaryszew in the thread above .. many thanks to him BTW

Comment: Why the hack a "braile reader" is preinstalled on Ubuntu?? I have the same issue

Answer (score 5):

As far I see you are using the version `1.0.5` of arduino IDE, I assume that you installed the one in the apt repositories.

You can either try to install one from the [snapcraft](https://snapcraft.io/arduino-mhall119) or the one from arduino's [website](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software).

Personally I used the latter one and anything worked like a charm.

Also either the case you can try to loon on `Tools`->`Port` if exists a port that is not a `/dev/ttyS0` one. Try to play with these options. Finally by searching on `dmesg` you can find out which port has been located for arduno as well.

Finally an another approach is to unplug your arduino plug it again and type the following command:

```
dmesg | tail
```

In order to record the last event as the one that happens when arduino is plugged in to a usb port. The command above will show you the correct port.

For better results you can use the following:

```
  dmesg | tail -f
```

And continioulsy plug and unplug the arduino from the usp port till you see any arduino related message. The `-f` parameter allows to show realtime the new logs.

Comment: That really helped, because for me it was actually the usb cable which didn't work. Only noticed by watching dmesg. After the change I only needed to add my user to the dialout group.

Comment: I get: ch341-uart converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0

Answer (score 3):

Your user account probably doesn't have permission to use the serial port.

Two ways to address this:

- Easiest, but not advised: Run the Arduino IDE as root (eg launch from the command line using `sudo`).
- The second, more advisable way to do it is to add your user to the `dialout` group, which has permission to use the serial port. Use the command `sudo adduser $USER dialout`. You will need to log out then log back in for it to take effect though (or [try this](https://superuser.com/a/354475/500826)). To list groups of current user use `groups` or `id -Gn`.

Once this is done, when you select the correct serial port (as others have mentioned maybe `/dev/ttyUSB0`) you should be able to write, allowing you to program the Arduino.

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0
```

or

```
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Comment: The OP is just asking for the Linux equivalent of COM1, nit that he cannot see /dev/ttyxyz...

Comment: Thank you. For me it was: sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0

Answer (score 1):

For serial stuff I would actually recommend using something like [minicom](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Minicom) it's easy to use and you actually see the /dev/tty to which it is bound. It's usually something like /dev/ttyS0

Edit: So it's not only a link answer `dmesg | grep tty` that's how you see which port your TTY is - see the link above for reference.

Comment: I went to serial port setup and found dev/tty8. Now what should I do?

Comment: And also my Arduino IDE 's tools -> serial ports is disabled.

Comment: Did you type into the terminal the dmesg | grep tty ? Can you post the output of it?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and struggled to fix it for a while. I tried the usual suggestions about adding myself to the dialout group and was frustrated that none of those tips helped. In the end, I realized I was using a backrev version of the Arduino IDE software, and once I upgraded, the problem went away.