# USB serial device not getting port in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: usb, 22.04, serial-port

I have a USB device that have been using for years in older Ubuntus to which I can talk via serial port. `lsusb` shows the device. I am now trying to find in which serial port it is (i.e. `/dev/whatever`), I have tried with [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144735/317682) and it is not showing up, I have also tried with `python3 -m serial.tools.list_ports` and get `no ports found`. I already uninstalled brltty as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1417483/823631) and restarted the PC. Still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to make a USB serial device appear in the /dev folder.  Open a terminal:

```
sudo apt remove brltty
```

This solution is from a previous post: [AskUbuntu question 1403705](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403705/dev-ttyusb0-not-present-in-ubuntu-22-04)

I found this solution in August and needed to resolved the issue with another computer this December!