# /dev/ttyUSB0 not present

Tags: usb

I have a USB serial device. In a Xubuntu 20.04 computer it works perfectly, but when connected into an Ubuntu 22.04 computer I have it does not create the `/dev/ttyUSB0`, or any. The command `lsusb` properly lists this device, and `lsusb -v -s` prints this:

```
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0403:7168 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x0403 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd
  idProduct          0x7168 
  bcdDevice            6.00
  iManufacturer           1 Sensirion
  iProduct                2 EKS2
  iSerial                 3 EKS23Z5LQG
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength       0x0020
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass    255 Vendor Specific Subclass
      bInterfaceProtocol    255 Vendor Specific Protocol
      iInterface              2 EKS2
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x02  EP 2 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

I have already tried several things, like [the brltty thing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403705/dev-ttyusb0-not-present-in-ubuntu-22-04), checking that my user is in the dialout group, etc.

Comment: Watch `sudo journalctl --follow` as you connect your device.